# Converting MP4 to FLV in Adobe Media Encoder fails

Tags: video-conversion, mp4, flv, adobe-media-encoder

I am trying to encode a .mp4 to a .flv

I've tried using the [Adobe Media Encoder](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=4227) but the video is lost in the conversion process, leaving me a black screen and some audio.

I have yet to find something that can do this successfully *for free*.  I found [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/index.html), which looks promising... but I can't figure out how to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to update the Adobe Media Encoder.  I have a CS4 license so I don't know if it is free or not, but it is definitely my preference over anything else I've used (or tried to use).

Answer (score 1):

**Total Video Converter.**
No is free but, you have download a trial.
During this evaluation period, the software has full function except some limitations.

And [here a video](http://www.ojosoft.com/how-to-convert/mp4-to-flv-converter.html) with the proccess to convert.

**And a free program could be SUPER. Powerful but free.**

try this in [next link](http://www.erightsoft.com/SUPER.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should try **[MediaCoder](http://www.mediacoderhq.com/)**.

> MediaCoder is a **free** universal media
>   transcoder since 2005. It integrates
>   most popular audio/video codecs and
>   tools in an elegant and transparent
>   manner into an all-in-one transcoding
>   solution. With a flexible and
>   extendable architecture, latest codecs
>   and tools are updated added in
>   constantly. MediaCoder intends to be
>   the swiss army knife for media
>   transcoding in all time.
>
> Supported Formats:
>
> - **Video:** H.264, XviD, DivX, MPEG 1/2/4,    **Flash Video**, Theora
>     (Open Video),    Dirac, H.263,
>     RealVideo, Windows    Media Video,
>     MJPEG
> - **Container:** AVI, MPEG PS, MPEG TS,    Matroska, **MP4**, PMP,
>     RealMedia, ASF,    MTS/AVCHD*,
>     Quicktime*, OGM*
> - **Lossy Audio:** MP3, Vorbis, LC-AAC,    HE-AAC v1/v2, AC-3, MPEG
>     Audio L2,    MusePack, Speex, AMR,
>     Windows Media    Audio, ADPCM, mp3PRO*
> - **Lossless Audio:** FLAC, WavPack,    Monkey's Audio, OptimFrog, ALAC, TTA, 
>     PCM
> - **Storage and Streaming:** CD, DVD, VCD,    SVCD, CUESheet*, HTTP*, FTP*,
>     RTSP*,    UDP*

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue on my iMAC and found a free converter - search for "Kigo" - I use it pretty much every day and haven't had any issues with it. Not sure if it works on PC though.